# Best way to install custom modules in Ray kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, kubernetes, ray

Following the docs as suggested here: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/kubernetes.html I am able to execute the sample programs and submit jobs.
I would like to know the best way to install custom modules in Ray cluster.
I know of a way to manually login to each worker and head nodes and install modules using `pip install` or `conda install`. But, it doesn't help much.
I would like to automate job submission such that I just provide the list of requirements to be installed and python program and it should execute this as a batch job. Could you please help?